# If $(a_n)$ is a complex sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{k^n} = 0,\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ then $a_n = 0$ for all $ n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $(a_n)$ be a complex sequence such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{k^n} = 0,\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$$
>   Prove that $a_n = 0$ for all $ n$.

I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this, but I'm feeling low on inspiration right now. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: (I sometimes wonder how much effort is done to check if a question has been answered before. Just typing the formula `\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{k^n} = 0` into the search field revealed a "duplicate".)

Comment: @MartinR In general you can safely assume that *zero* effort has been put in checking for duplicates. Most people don't care, some don't even know how (or show any interest in learning how).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Well,  my remark was meant for authors of both questions and answers, and I would expect something else from a >10K user – but I'll stop the rant now ...

Comment: @MartinR: I usually look for duplicates when I feel there should be one, but somehow it didn't occur to me that this would probably be one, though in hindsight it's obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the related function $z \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ and think about what it means to it being zero on $\frac{1}{k}$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$.

Comment: This function is clearly analytic on $\mathbb{C}$. But since $1\in f^{-1}(0)$, and since $1$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = 0 \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. And hence we must have $(a_n) = 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @elDin0: Er your sequence is $(\frac{1}{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, and so I don't see how $1$ being a limit point of $\mathbb{C}$ is relevant?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm really asleep today. I mean since 0 is a limit point of $f^{-1}(z)$ and $0\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @elDin0: Then yes correct. Basically remember that if the analytic function is zero on any sequence that converges within its domain, then it must be zero on the whole domain. Often it's much easier to think in terms of sequences than limit points (though they're more or less equivalent).

Comment: @elDin0: Didn't notice.. you mean "$0$ is a limit point of $f^{-1}(0)$".

Comment: Yes. Another typo! Thanks very much for your help.